# wampsharp session variable in rpc

Tags: c#, autobahn, autobahnws, wampsharp

I've a websocket service written in c# with wampsharp at server side and I wonder to know if there's a way to store/retrieve session's related variables or in alternative how to know the caller's session id.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported currently by WampSharp.

This reminds an advanced profile [feature](https://github.com/wamp-proto/wamp-proto/blob/master/spec/advanced/caller-identification.md) of WAMPv2, WampSharp supports currently only WAMPv2 basic profile.

You are welcome to open an issue or a pull request for this on the GitHub page.

*Update*: this is now possible with WampSharp v1.2.1.6-beta. See [release notes](http://wampsharp.net/release-notes/wampsharp-v1.2.1.6-beta-release-notes/#caller-identification).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the moment I've found a little workaround, using raw callee I can retrieve the session id so for my purpose I've used a simple key-value structure. In the next days I'll pull a request on GitHub.